# wpf - Is there an event notifying that an element been rendered?

Tags: wpf, render

I have a chart that its rendering\drawing takes some time.
I want to do something after it's appeares , is there any event generally in wpf that can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there isn't, but there seem to be workarounds, see here: [msdn link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/380674/add-event-to-signal-wpf-rendering-completion)